# Border-radius rendering bug when in overflow: hidden

Tags: css

I have a bug in the rendering of border-radius under all major browsers (tested: IE 9, Chrome, Firefox).

What happen is that I have a menu bar with border-radius, and in there some links width a background color. In order to keep the button inside the shape of the menu, I set a overflow hidden on the menu container. Until there all goes well, but then, there's a little white line appearing on the corner edge.

I made a reduced test case here: http://dabblet.com/gist/3828561

Anyone have a solution to overcome this one? Thanks!

Comment: I would say that is not bug just a complexity of the rendering needed for rounded corners i.e. anti-aliasing. I should imagine that the code to render that rounded corner is pretty complex. Having messed around with your code and by adding a border it seems clear to me that the white background is slightly larger than the radius of the css radius - take it up with each of the browser vendors...

Comment: a fix would be to add a background image with the correct blue colour to mask that 'underlap' of the css radius

Comment: White line on corners determined by `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);` property of `.outer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dimensions-dependent solution...but maybe that's OK since it's a menu bar not a content holder?  Anyway, you can set `border-radius` on your inner elements, give the parent a height, and also use that height value for the `line-height` of the inner elements.

Once you apply the height/line-height, you don't have to use `overflow: hidden`.

Since your menu bar has a border radius of `3px`, apply the same rounding to the appropriate corners of the first menu item like so:

`.outer .inner:first-of-type { border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; }`

And make the corresponding corners of the bar even more rounded, to hide them beneath the first menu item:

`.outer { border-radius: 10px 3px 3px 10px; }`

http://dabblet.com/gist/3828755

Comment: Hey thanks, I guess this is the right way to go. Although, you added a lot of code and your final solution isn't much flexible. I made a simpler version here : http://dabblet.com/gist/3828881